# I am using Odoo 13 and I have install a module from odoo 12

Tags: inheritance, odoo, accounting

I have this problem all over again. I tried to install a module that has a version 12 from my odoo 13 and do some removals like api multi and other stuff but the problem is this:

"account.invoice_form does not exist" I don't understand either.

I tried to check the odoo 13 migration but it didn't mention about account.invoice_form or the action_invoice_draft.

I tried to change this to move_form but move_form does not exist either and also view_move_form. There is no account.invoice_form.

Hope someone will help. I thank you for this.

```
    Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 640, in apply_inheritance_specs
    source = apply_inheritance_specs(source, specs_tree,
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\tools\template_inheritance.py", line 229, in apply_inheritance_specs
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Element '<button name="action_invoice_draft">' cannot be located in parent view

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 712, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 674, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 577, in _tag_record
    record = model._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 4067, in _load_records
    records = self._load_records_create([data['values'] for data in to_create])
  File "d:\devs\odoo\addons\website\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 148, in _load_records_create
    records = super(View, self)._load_records_create(values)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 3981, in _load_records_create
    return self.create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-31>", line 2, in create
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 344, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 473, in create
    return super(View, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in create
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 344, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 3762, in create
    fields[0].determine_inverse(batch_recs)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\fields.py", line 1114, in determine_inverse
    getattr(records, self.inverse)()
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 299, in _inverse_arch
    view.write(data)
  File "d:\devs\odoo\addons\website\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 51, in write
    return super(View, self).write(vals)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 490, in write
    return super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 3551, in write
    real_recs._validate_fields(set(vals) - set(inverse_fields))
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 1167, in _validate_fields
    check(self)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 385, in _check_xml
    view_def = view.read_combined(['arch'])
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 716, in read_combined
    arch = self.apply_view_inheritance(arch_tree, root.id, self.model)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 665, in apply_view_inheritance
    source = self.apply_inheritance_specs(source, specs_tree, view_id)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 644, in apply_inheritance_specs
    self.raise_view_error(str(e), inherit_id)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 592, in raise_view_error
    raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Element '<button name="action_invoice_draft">' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `account.invoice_form.inherit`
[view_id: 1547, xml_id: n/a, model: account.move, parent_id: 714]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 619, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 309, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 664, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 345, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\service\model.py", line 93, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 338, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 910, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 510, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "d:\devs\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1324, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "d:\devs\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1312, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 395, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 382, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-58>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 72, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 463, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 573, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 421, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 225, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 68, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 736, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 803, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 715, in parse
    pycompat.reraise(
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 13, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 712, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 674, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 577, in _tag_record
    record = model._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 4067, in _load_records
    records = self._load_records_create([data['values'] for data in to_create])
  File "d:\devs\odoo\addons\website\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 148, in _load_records_create
    records = super(View, self)._load_records_create(values)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 3981, in _load_records_create
    return self.create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-31>", line 2, in create
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 344, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 473, in create
    return super(View, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in create
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 344, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 3762, in create
    fields[0].determine_inverse(batch_recs)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\fields.py", line 1114, in determine_inverse
    getattr(records, self.inverse)()
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 299, in _inverse_arch
    view.write(data)
  File "d:\devs\odoo\addons\website\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 51, in write
    return super(View, self).write(vals)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 490, in write
    return super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 3551, in write
    real_recs._validate_fields(set(vals) - set(inverse_fields))
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\models.py", line 1167, in _validate_fields
    check(self)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 385, in _check_xml
    view_def = view.read_combined(['arch'])
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 716, in read_combined
    arch = self.apply_view_inheritance(arch_tree, root.id, self.model)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 665, in apply_view_inheritance
    source = self.apply_inheritance_specs(source, specs_tree, view_id)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 644, in apply_inheritance_specs
    self.raise_view_error(str(e), inherit_id)
  File "D:\devs\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 592, in raise_view_error
    raise ValueError(message)
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Element '<button name="action_invoice_draft">' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `account.invoice_form.inherit`
[view_id: 1547, xml_id: n/a, model: account.move, parent_id: 714]" while parsing file:/d:/devs/odoo/custom/sale_amendment/views/sale_order_views.xml:2, near
<odoo>

    <record id="sale_order_view_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.view.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <data><button name="action_cancel" position="before">
                <button name="go_amendment" type="object" string="Amendment" attrs="{'invisible':[('state', 'in', ('draft','sent','done','cancel','amendment'))]}" groups="base.group_user"/>
            </button>

            <button name="action_draft" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="states">amendment</attribute>
            </button>

            <field name="partner_id" position="after">
                <field name="amendment_no" readonly="1"/>
            </field>

            <xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page[2]" position="after">
                <page string="Amendments">
                    <field name="old_amendment_ids">
                        <tree>
                            <field name="name" string="Quotation"/>
                            <field name="create_date" string="Quotation Date"/>
                            <field name="state" invisible="1"/>
                            <field name="create_uid" string="Superseeded by"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </page>
            </xpath>
        </data></field>
    </record>

    <record id="account_invoice_view_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.invoice_form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">account.move</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_move_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <button name="action_invoice_draft" position="replace"/>
        </field>
    </record>   

</odoo>
```

Answer (score 1):

In odoo 13 account.invoice model have been removed and account.move is directly used.

as per you inheritance code button **`action_invoice_draft`** is not available in `account.view_move_form` if you need to replace reset button , name is **`button_draft`** to  be used.

```
<record id="account_invoice_view_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.invoice_form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">account.move</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_move_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <button name="button_draft" position="replace"/>
        </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this since I need that module from 3rd party